# Converting SmbFile(Samba) to bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, samba, smb

Is there any easy way to convert SmbFile to bitmap, something like this - Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mSmbFile.getPath()) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(SmbFile file){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new SmbFileInputStream(file),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;

        System.gc();

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new SmbFileInputStream(file), null, o2);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```